# From symbolic to numeric in matlab

Tags: matlab, numeric, symbolic-math

In my problem, there are some matrices like

```
T_x=[ cos(q1) sin(q1+q2) cos(q1) -sin(q2);
      0       0           1      -1;
      sin(q4) 0           1      q1;
      0       0           0      1]
```

Moreover I have the `q` values such as: `q=[0.2 0.05 -2 -3.5]`

How can I insert the `q` values into `T_x` matrix?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to have a matrix-returning function that takes the values as an argument:

```
>> T_x = @(q) [ cos(q(1)) sin(q(1)+q(2)) cos(q(1)) -sin(q(2));
                0          0             1         -1;
                sin(q(4))  0             1         q(1);
                0          0             0         1];

>> T_x([.2 .05 -2 -3.5])

ans =

    0.9801    0.2474    0.9801   -0.0500
         0         0    1.0000   -1.0000
    0.3508         0    1.0000    0.2000
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

This has the benefit of not needing the symbolic package - it's portable to Octave.

Comment: While this works, and its an elegant solution, it is not an answer to "From symbolic to numeric in matlab"

Comment: In my problem, there are different T_x matrices and als q values changes in each step.

Comment: I also tried subs comand but it didn't work.

for ii=1:4
T_val=subs(T_x, 'q%d',ii', q(ii))
end

but in each step it forgot the previous ones
(if ii=2, it puts q1 as q1 (not 0))

Comment: @user70299 You can substitute all q's at once, no need to do it in a loop. It's OK that there are different `T_x` matrices and different `q`'s. You can have as many functions as you need. You can even generate the functions programmatically by `eval`-uating a string. Please amend the question with details of the *exact* code that you're using. Don't put the code in the comments - put the entire code, copy-pastable into octave/matlab, into the question, so that we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subs`](http://build-your-own-particle-detector.org/models/lhc-micro-models).

```
syms q1 q2 q3 q4

T_x = [ cos(q1) sin(q1+q2) cos(q1) -sin(q2);
        0       0          1       -1;
        sin(q4) 0          1       q1;
        0       0          0       1];

q = [.2 .05 -2 -3.5];

subs(T_x, [q1 q2 q3 q4], q)

ans =

[  cos(1/5), sin(1/4), cos(1/5), -sin(1/20)]
[         0,        0,        1,         -1]
[ -sin(7/2),        0,        1,        1/5]
[         0,        0,        0,          1]

double(ans)

ans =

    0.9801    0.2474    0.9801   -0.0500
         0         0    1.0000   -1.0000
    0.3508         0    1.0000    0.2000
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

Just do it for all the symbolic variables you want!